# "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Language" option list missed

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, llvm

I am trying to change the "C++ Standard Library" option in Xcode's project configuration, but the option list is not there! 
The option list "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Language" is missed. I have made the project with CMake, but last time I did (with Xcode 4.3) this didn't happend.
How can I get the option list back? Any idea?

Comment: What's the compiler got to do with the library?

Comment: Some libraries I am using needs some characteristics not present in the Xcodes c libraries. So, I need to specify to use c++ standard with this flag. With previous versions it works this way.